# Does django have a Console tool like javascript console of Chrome?

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

for example

views.py

```
def index(request):
    foo = 123+456
    return render_to_response('forum/index.html', {'foo':foo})
```

If I want to see what foo is, I have to put a {{foo}} in the target template.Is there a tool like the console in Chrome, with which I can get a instant result without a {{foo}} tag?